# Recursion Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

how many arrangments of RECURRENCERELATION have the firs R preceding the first c or the first E preceding the First N

The answer is $ [2(\frac{5!}{3!2!}) {7+12-1 \choose 12}(\frac{12!}{4!2!})]-[(\frac{5!}{3!2!}){7+6-1 \choose 6}(\frac{5!}{3!2!}){6+13-1 \choose 6}6!]$

I am literally lost on this problem. I know they are using PIE, since that first answer has to be r before c and e before n but they are the same answer so they are just multiplying them by 2. Then they must be subtracting when they happen at the same time, but that is where I am at a total loss

Comment: Would you tell me the connection to infinitary combinatorics? Otherwise, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 4):

There's a much more straightforward formula:
$$\frac{18!}{4!\,4!\,2!\,2!} \left(\frac23 + \frac23 - \frac49\right)$$
where:

- We divide the $18!$ total permutations of $18$ letters by $4!$, $4!$, $4!$, and $2$! to account for the four R's, four E's, two C's, and two N's being identical;
- the fraction of permutations in which the first R comes before the first C is $\frac23$: it happens in $10$ out of $15$ permutations of RRRRCC;
- same for the first E coming before the first N;
- the R and C ordering is independent of the E and N ordering, so we subtract off $\left(\frac23\right)^2 = \frac49$ to account for the overlap.

The formula you give results in the same number, but figuring out how it works seems more like an exercise in learning what *not* to do.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out $ [2(\frac{5!}{3!2!}) {7+12-1 \choose 12}(\frac{12!}{4!2!})]-[(\frac{5!}{3!2!}){7+6-1 \choose 6}(\frac{5!}{3!2!}){6+13-1 \choose 6}6!]$

$(\frac{5!}{3!2!})$ =The first part is is technically R_C_C_ and placing the the 3-R's into the three places with repeat allowed

$(\frac{5!}{3!2!})$= E_N_N_ and placing the 3-E's into the three spots with repeat allowed.

${7+12-1 \choose 12}$The 12 letters left then can go into _R_R_R_R_C_C_ with repeat allowed

${7+12-1 \choose 12}$ 12 letters left into  _E_E_E_E_N_N_ with repeat allowed.

$(\frac{12!}{4!2!})$=arrange the 12 letters left in the first case we have 4 repeated and 2 repeat letters and in the second case we have the same things.

Since we have two identical combinations, just one was done and multiplied by 2.

The second part being subtracted is the intersection of the two sets

$(\frac{5!}{3!2!})$==which is the same as ${3+3-1 \choose 3}$we have R_C_C_ with the 3-R's being placed into the 3 spots with repeat allowed

$(\frac{5!}{3!2!})$=which is the same as ${3+3-1 \choose 3}$we have E_N_N_ with the 3-E's being placed into the 3 spots with repeat allowed

${7+6-1 \choose 6}$= _R_R_R_R_C_C_ here we have 7 spots for the 4-E's and 2-C's to go into with repeats allowed.

${6+13-1 \choose 6}6!$= _R_R_R_R_C_C_E_E_E_E_N_N_ here we have only 6 letters left to go into 13 spots with repeat allowed and the 6! is the way to arrange those 6 letters left after placing them.